# Interrupting a blocking method before the method call

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, race-condition

I'm reading this book, (O'Reillys Java Threads 3rd ed., which for now has very bad explanations), and I have encountered this code:

```
//in RandomCharacterGenerator class
public void run( ) {
    while (!isInterrupted()) {
            nextCharacter( );
            try {

                Thread.sleep(getPauseTime( ));

            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                return;
            }
    }
}
```

And the following explanation (producer is the instance of upper class in the main thread):

```
producer.interrupt( );
```

> If the main thread executes this statement while the RandomCharacterGenerator thread is sleeping, the RandomCharacterGenerator thread gets the interrupted exception and immediately returns from the run() method. Otherwise, when the character-feeding thread next gets to the top of its loop, it sees that the interrupted flag has been set and returns from its run() method then. Either way, the random character generator thread completes its task.
>
> Note that this technique does not completely eliminate the possibility that we sleep for some amount of time after the thread is asked to stop. It's possible for the main thread to call the interrupt() method just after the RandomCharacterGenerator has called the isInterrupted() method. The character-reading thread still executes the sleep() method, which won't be interrupted (since the main thread has already completed the interrupt() method). This is another example of a race condition that we solve in the next chapter. Since the race condition in this case is benign (it just means we sleep one more time than we'd like), this is sufficient for our purposes.

Second paragraph is completely unclear to me. My first question is: How can we sleep one more cycle? If we interrupt the thread when sleeping it goes out of run, if we interrupt before sleep it will interrupt sleep as soon as it starts sleeping (I tested that, and I think that's true? Am I right), if we interrupt after sleep it will brake the loop.

Second question: In this example (this is the whole code from the book) is the check in loop completely unnecessary, and can it stand while (true) with the same outcome, so that first paragraph about the top of the loop is complete nonsense?

Comment: I think this example does not use Thread.interrupt but a custom boolean interruption flag instead. So producer.interrupt() just sets this boolean flag to true but does not interrupt the sleeping thread.

Comment: No, it does not, example before is with setting a flag, this example uses Thread.interrupt, producer extends thread, and does not override interrupt

Comment: OK, if that's the case, then you're right. Thread interruption will cause the sleeping thread to (more or less) immediately throw an InterruptedException. No race condition.

Comment: @croraf you may find `Java Concurrency in Practice` more handy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The book is wrong. Interrupting the thread before it sleeps will make the sleep() method throw an InterruptedException immediately.

Quote from *Java Concurrency in Practice*:

> A good way to think about interruption is that it does not actually interrupt a running thread; it just requests that the thread interrupt itself at the next convenient opportunity. (These opportunities are called cancellation points.) Some methods, such as wait, sleep, and join, take such requests seriously, throwing an exception when they receive an interrupt request **or encounter an already set interrupt status upon entry**.

(emphasis mine)

In this particular example, using `while(true)` would lead to the same effect. But in other cases, if the loop never calls an interruptible method, or if you want to exit as soon as possible, you'll have to regularly check if the thread is interrupted to be able to detect the interruption.

Comment: Good answer! Good book!

Comment: Ty your comment at the end is the same concept said at Oracle on-line tutorial, but the book confused me, more so I'm not native English speaker. I'll check the suggested book.

Answer (score 0):

The book believes you will spend an extra cycle in the following case:

```
RandomCharacterGenerator -> isInterrupted = false;

Main -> interrupt()

RandomCharacterGenerator -> runs through code
RandomCharacterGenerator -> sleeps
RandomCharacterGenerator -> isInterrupted = true
```

It actually will interrupt on the sleep, but the thing <strike>it is trying to get at</strike> that is important is that you may run through the code one more time after calling interrupt()

Comment: I think that the author believes that what james large said is true, but it isn't.

Comment: Yup.  I was wrong, and the book is wrong.  I just tried the experiment, and Thread.sleep() throws immediately if the flag is set.

Comment: Just goes to show how careful everybody has to be with predicting the outcome of concurrent threads :)